# Active list-group-item wrong color on page load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 4.3 list-group-item that I have assigned a black background to for active state like so

```css
.list-group-item:active {
  background-color: black !important;
  color:white;
  border: none;
}
```

This works when element is triggered active by click, however on the page load the first element is the default bootstrap blue.  On inspection this element has identical class and 'active' state as my custom css so why the blue color?  I can remove it by removing 'active' from the  class but then background is white which is not ideal.

```html
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Wikipedia</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The active selector is working as intended: [CSS :active Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

The background of the list item element is black when you remove the active selector, did you mean that the rest of the page is white? You could just set the background colour of the parent div to be black as well?